# What does the handling stat do?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

All of the weapon stats are pretty self explanatory and does experience noticeable differences with increase/decrease. Handling, however, I am unable to tell what it actually does.

Even increasing/decreasing the stat with the help of attachments/variants doesn't seem to change anything (tested in the shooting range).

What does handling affect?

Answer (score 1):

The Handling stat affects how fast you can switch gun (with that gun), Aim Down Sight (ADS), and reload. Everything that has to do with handling the gun itself.

**Edit:** Although most online forums tend to agree with my first statement (up here), a lot of people tend to agree with what [this video](http://youtu.be/aCUdAjFpk1g?t=4m40s) says: Handling only slightly reduces the hipfire recoil.

Comment: is the amount per point really just unnoticeable then? I have the [NA-45 Feint](http://www.codawpro.com/weapons/na-45/) which increases handling by 2 pips, but Swapping between guns in the shooting range feels *no* different. They scope and reload pretty much same rate (I didn't stopwatch, but they felt the same).

Comment: After looking deeper into the web I found another alternative, which I didn't test by myself though (added in the Edit clause of my answer).

Answer (score -2):

handling is the hip fire spread (confirmed by driftor)

Answer (score -3):

It affects how fast you can maneuver the weapon.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! Although this answer technically speaking answers the question, we would appreciate if you could elaborate, perhaps with examples or videos to back up your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Handling determines how fast you can ADS the weapon. http://www.codawpro.com/general/cod-advanced-warfare-weapon-stats-explained/

Comment: Please don't just link elsewhere for your answer.  Summarize the relevant parts here.  That way, if ever that site goes down, your answer is still valid.  Besides, that saves people a click.